# How do I delete a NPM project?

Tags: npm

I pushed some junk code into npm.  How do I delete the project?  There's a better alternative.  I don't have any users for my project yet.

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the man pages `npm help unpublish`:

```
DESCRIPTION
       This  removes  a  package version from the registry, deleting its entry
       and removing the tarball.

       If no version is specified, or if all versions  are  removed  then  the
       root package entry is removed from the registry entirely.
```

The package was still there for me after `npm unpublish --force`.

`npm info` listed all the versions.  `npm unpublish package@x.x.x --force` removed them individually.  After that I checked npmjs.org and the package page said: "This package has been unpublished"

Comment: *So* odd that they don't provide a means to delete a project via the NPM website. Thanks for sharing the solution.

Comment: The command that works for me is: `npm unpublish mypackagename --force`